# Making an inset rounded shape in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create this shape in React Native without using an image:
[image: inset rounded corner]
but so far I haven't be able to create an inset rounded corner.

More precisely this is this part I am struggling with:
[image]

I could make a rounded circle on the side, but I need the shape to be transparent.

I had a look at this [great article](https://codedaily.io/tutorials/22/The-Shapes-of-React-Native) but have not been able to round an inset corner/border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing it, not purely css though but you will be able to see the background behind it.

If you have 2 small images of the shape circle on the left and right (png). Connect them via inner View and add top View and bottom View. The content is the fourth View which is positioned absolute and I made it dynamic.

*Also if you need to change the color of the image - you could use [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) library, convert these small circles into svg and pass the color prop. This might work.*

This is the code:

```js
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 24;

class Ticket extends Component {
  state = {
    contentHeight: 50
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: this.state.contentHeight / 2 - IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2, borderTopRightRadius: 4, borderTopLeftRadius: 4 }} />
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Image source={images.circleLeft} />
          <View style={{ height: IMAGE_HEIGHT, backgroundColor: 'white', flex: 1 }} />
          <Image source={images.circleRight} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: this.state.contentHeight / 2 - IMAGE_HEIGHT / 2, borderBottomRightRadius: 4, borderBottomLeftRadius: 4 }} />
        <View
          onLayout={(event) => {
            const {height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
            this.setState({contentHeight: height});
          }}
          style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 30, right: 30, backgroundColor: 'white' }}
        >
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
          <Text>Dynamic content</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**This is the outcome, visible background:**

[image]

**Example of circle left image, its red for the display purpose, you would need white if you want to have white background**:
[image]

Comment: Ah. A pity there is still a need for an image but I guess that would work

Answer (score 2):

**You can add white circle from left and right side and set left,right values in minus to show half circle**

**Try this code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

export default class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: 300,
            height: 150,
            backgroundColor: "red",
            borderRadius: 8,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              borderRadius: 25,
              left: -25,
              top: 45,
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              right: -25,
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              borderRadius: 25,
              top: 45,
              backgroundColor: "white",
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**App Preview**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I need the circle to be transparent so we can see the background behind.